# Angular momentum of the Moon (or any body orbiting another orbiting body)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, planets

Let the Moon have angular velocity $\omega$ around the Earth. The Earth itself revolves with velocity $V$ around the Sun. The radius vectors are $r_i$ from Sun to a point on the Moon, $r_i'$ from Earth to the point and $R$ from Sun to Earth. $r_i=R+r_i'$

The angular momentum of the Moon with respect to the Sun is therefore
$\sum_i m_i(\vec{R}+\vec{r_i'})\times(\vec{V}+(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i'}))=M\vec{R}\times \vec{V}+\vec{\omega}\sum_i m_i r_i'^2+\sum_i m_i(\vec{r_i'}\times \vec{V})+ \vec{\omega} \sum_i m_i(\vec{R}\cdot \vec{r_i'})$.

If one would prove that [orbital and spin angular momenta be added](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AROKWyI34N0&t=505s) then the 3rd and 4th term would now be ejected since the sums are both zeroes, but they don't seem to cancel for the Moon. However, intuitively it seems to me that the angular momentum should simply be $\vec{L}=M\vec{R}\times \vec{V}+\vec{\omega}\sum_i m_i r_i'^2$. Is this right, and if so, where do the last two terms go?

Answer (score 4):

The last two terms do not go to zero because you are not using the center of mass. The theorem that says that total angular momentum is the sum of orbital angular momentum and spin angular momentum does not work with any point. The point of consideration, $\mathbf{R}$, is required to be the center of mass of the object (the Moon in this case). Then the last two terms are proportional to $\sum m\mathbf{r}'$, which is zero by definition of center of mass. This is mentioned in section 8.1.2 of Morin's *Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions*.